# Archiving an object and then unarchiving it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

```
 NSString *cachePath= [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

 cachePath= [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"nerd.archive"];

 //    Load the cached channel
 RSSChannel *cachedChannel= [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:cachePath];
 NSLog(@"unarchived data- %@ %p, x value- %d",cachedChannel,cachedChannel,cachedChannel.x);

 //    if one hasn't already been cached, create a blank one to fill up
 if (!cachedChannel) {
     cachedChannel= [[RSSChannel alloc] init];
     NSLog(@"cachedChannel initialised- %@ %p",cachedChannel,cachedChannel);
     cachedChannel.x=5;
 }
```

In the above code-snippet, the pointer variable cachedChannel is assigned with the return value of `unarchiveObjectWithFile`: message. Now obviously in the first run, this would return  nil but the pointer will be initialized later on in the “if-statement”. Lets say the `cachedChannel` var is something like

```
cachedChannel= [RSSChannel:0X123ff]
```

After the code has gone through its first run, the object assigned to `cachedChannel` would become serialized.
When i run the test project the second time and the `unarchiveObjectWithFile`: message is passed so that the serialized object is returned and assigned to the `cachedChannel` pointer var, it shows up as a different object with a different object-id.
Instead of cachedChannel pointing to `[RSSChannel:0X123ff]` object, it is now holding some other object like `[RSSChannel:0X445ee]`
How could this be possible?? Shouldn’t the object that was serialized before be the one to be unarchived later on with the same object-id residing in the same heap memory location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could this be possible?? Shouldn’t the object that was serialized before be the one to be unarchived later on with the same object-id residing in the same heap memory location?

Not at all. This is, as you say, happening later. And at this later time, the memory situation is completely different. Think of it this way: if you have code that creates an object from scratch, e.g. `[[MyObject alloc] init]`, and you run the app today and then quit it and run the app again tomorrow, those two instances of MyObject, even though they play the very same role in the life of the app, will have two different memory addresses.

Moreover, what we are creating as we unarchive the object is a *different* instance from the one that was archived - identical, in whatever ways you have specified while archiving / unarchiving, to the original, but a different instance. Think of it this way: archive-unarchive is an elaborate way of making a *copy* of the object - and two copies of one instance are, obviously, two different objects.

After all, you could archive the object, hang on to the original, and immediately unarchive the archived object. That would be two different objects. But they could not possibly live at the same memory address!

It sounds like you may be trying to use the memory address as some sort of unique identifier. Beware of that. If a thing needs a unique identifier, *give* it a unique identifier *as a property*. Don't rely on the memory address at runtime for *anything*, except during debugging to confirm that two instances are one and the same instance.

Comment: yeah it was wrong to identify the two different objects based on addresses.. I thought they had to have same object ids. But if archived and the unarchived objects are completely different then wouldn't their states be different as well? e.g.: items (being an array object thats initialized) ought to hold same objects as items (array obj being unarchived). Isn't the whole idea of unarchiving an archived obj meant to restore the previous state from the filesystem?

Comment: Sure, but what address it is held in memory is not part of its "previous state". It is utterly irrelevant. And no, their states would not be different, because you have carefully arranged things so that they have the same state. As I said in my answer, it's just like how `copy` works.

Comment: Ok i think i got it.Please correct if I'm wrong. Preserving the state of the archived obj and restoring it as the new object's state is the job of encodeWithCoder: and decodeWithCoder: messages respectively.

Comment: It was very foolish of me to look for similarities between the objects based on their object ids. object ids basically indicate memory locations that aren't even remotely relevant here. What i wanted to say was the similarities in the states of the two objects (one newly initialized, the other unarchived)

Comment: "Preserving the state of the archived obj and restoring it as the new object's state is the job of encodeWithCoder: and decodeWithCoder: messages respectively" 100% correct! That is what I was saying in my answer when I wrote: "archive-unarchive is an elaborate way of making a _copy_ of the object"

Comment: You have asked 29 questions on Stack Overflow, of which 21 have received answers. But you have _never, not once_, accepted any answers. That is totally against the spirit of Stack Overflow. You need to consider how Stack Overflow citizenship works. Asking and never accepting is just leeching. Why should anyone ever help you if you behave like that? Please go back over your old questions, look at the answers, and if you have been helped / satisfied by one of the answers to a question, _accept_ it (click the checkmark). - Including mine, if I have helped you.

Comment: I apologize for this. I just didn't know about this concept of accepting until now (as you pointed it out). I thought leaving a reply saying something like  thanx or something that expresses appreciation like 'good explanation' or 'gotcha' was sufficient. I didn't intend to not do the right thing. I wasn't aware of this. How am I supposed to accept the answer again. You mentioned clicking  a check mark. I didnt see one.

Comment: @rahulbsb There is a big empty check mark to the top left of _every_ answer anyone has ever given you (under the number with the arrows). Click it to accept that answer as the answer that helped you. Please also read the Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers